# QWinWidget's position is always 0 (zero)

Tags: qt, mfc, qt4, qt-mfc-migration

I hosted a QWinWidget in a CView and want it to stay at a designated position when resizing. But QWinWidget always moves to (0, 0), i.e. left-top corner of the CView.

I tried to debug in this way:

```
QWinWidget* pWidget = new QWinWidget(pCView);
pWidget->move(50, 50);
QPoint pos = pWidget->pos();
```

***Note that: the pos is always (0, 0).***

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to create a child [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html) of the [`QWinWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/qwinwidget.html) to be able to position it.  However, I have never used the mfc-migration tool kit.

Comment: Yes, there is a child QWidget. Moving the child QWidget does not affect QWinWidget's position. 

I found that QWinWidget does not have parent QWidget, while the QWidget.pos() is the position in its parent widget coordinate, so it is always  zero.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to firstly show the widget, then move:

```
pWidget->show();
pWidget->move( 50, 50 );
```